# Trigonometry in CLDC 1.0 / MIDP 2.0 application

Tags: java, java-me, midp, cldc

How can I use trigonometry in CLDC 1.0 / MIDP 2.0 application? I need "sin cos tan asin acos atan atan2" functions from standart Math library.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gnat knows](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5372476)

Answer (score 0):

update to [prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793534/trigonometry-in-cldc-1-0-midp-2-0-application/1793564#1793564)

> [gnat knows](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5372476)

Above link to Sun Forums became [dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) after migration to Oracle.

If memory serves, back then I suggested to consider [MicroFloat library](http://www.dclausen.net/projects/microfloat/).

There is also a chance that mentioned *Sun forums thread* was migrated to this one: [Sin & Cos with CLDC](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1695831). Since message formatting was broken in migration and since no one knows if migrated thread will stay where it is now, here's the "snapshot" of what is there:

- CLDC 1.0 (JSR 30) doesn't have float / double and trigonometric functions
  For devices limited to CLDC 1.0, [search Google for 'CLDC Math library'](http://www.google.com/search?q=CLDC+Math+library) - there's plenty info
- CLDC 1.1 (JSR 139) has some trigonometric and double / float functions in [Math package](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr139/java/lang/Math.html)
  of functions mentioned in question, *sin cos tan* are there, *asin acos atan atan2* aren't